# How to update nested documents in mongoose nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey guys I am struggling with updating a nested document w mongoose

```
flashcardDeck.updateOne({ _id: deck._id }, { $set: { flashcards[Math.floor(i/2)].side1: newFlashcardsArr[i]}});
```

for some reason the editor throws errors when I try to specify which flashcard to update.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What errors is it throwing? (And what editor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
const idx = Math.floor(i/2);
flashcardDeck.updateOne({ _id: deck._id }, { $set: { `flashcards.${idx}.side1`: newFlashcardsArr[i]}});
```